# `yarn upgrade` fails with "The engine "node" is incompatible with this module."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

when running `yarn upgrade` I get the following error:
error browserslist@4.13.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^6 || ^7 || ^8 || ^9 || ^10 || ^11 || ^12 || >=13.7". Got "13.6.0"

I'm running:
ubuntu 18.04
nodejs 13.6
yarn 1.21.1-1
rails 6.0.0

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error.

First of all, check your node version using

```
node -v
```

After that, upgrade node using the [n module from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n)

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

Then, recheck your node version.

I found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version), where there is more information, but for me it was just necessary what I put above.

Answer (score 1):

Just re-installed node and worked correctly after that.
Apparently version 13.1 was the issue...
You can check you version with this command :

```
node -v
```